# Heroku-cli: docker run exited with 127 after trying to deploy docker image of NodeJS app

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, heroku-cli

I tried to deploy my docker image to heroku using heroku-cli,
but I got this error:

```
$: heroku container:run web
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
 ▸    Error: docker run exited with 127
```

This docker image works fine in local with command `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 webApp`

Already tried to add PATH variable inside heroku, but it didn't help.
Tried to find out what does `heroku container:run web` run behind but still zero result.

I also found that the documentation of `heroku container` is obsolete, they said to run `heroku container:release web`, but after I check `heroku help container` there is no `heroku container:release`.